# React Js post array data to api

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, react-redux

I'm newbie.
How to post array data with rest api. This form data is looping from database.

I have Code Like this (Createreport.js):

```
  render() {
  const { data } = this.state;
  return (
       <form onSubmit={this.reportUpdate} method="post">
          <Input type="text"
                 onChange={this.handleInputChange} 
                 value={this.state.namaCustomer} 
                 name="namaCustomer" />

          {data.map((item, index) => (
          <Col xs="12" sm="4" key={item.product_id}>
             <Label htmlFor="text-input">Quantity :</Label>
             <Input type="number" id="text-input" onChange={this.handleQtyChange.bind(this, index)} value={this.state.qty['']} name={`qty[]${index}.qty`} placeholder="Quantity" />
             <Input type="number" onChange={this.handleProdChange.bind(this, index)} defaultValue={item.product_id} name={`product_id[]${index}.product_id`} />

              <Label htmlFor="text-input">Notes :</Label>
              <Input type="textarea" onChange={this.handleNoteChange.bind(this, index)} value={this.state.note['']} name={`note[]${index}.note`} rows="4"
                             placeholder="Content..." />
          </Col>
          ))}

          <Col xs="12">
            <Input 
                  type="submit" onClick={this.reportUpdate} value="Submit"/>
          </Col>
    );
  }
}

export default Createreport;
```

Comment: What does `this.reportUpdate` do? If anything, that function should do the posting...

Comment: parse from json:

Comment: So, when you submit the form you are just returning an object??

Comment: product_id only use default value. But "namaCustomer, note, and quantity" to input manually.

Comment: First of all, React is component based, So try to divide this into components. Then, try to get all your product details in json array (same as mentioned by @AriezJs) which is suitable to be saved on database

Comment: Please @AriezJs update your question instead of post the json in comment.

Comment: reportUpdate(e) {
              PostData('apireport/createreport', postData).then((result) => {
                let responseJson = result;
                let K = [responseJson.productData].concat(this.state.data);
                console.log(K);
                this.setState({
                  data: K , 
                  namaCustomer:'',
                  product_id: '',
                  qty: '',
                  note: ''
                });
              });
          }